# bash set variable from commandline argument

Tags: bash, shell

cat ./1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
set var1 = $1
echo var1 is $var1
```

kostas@elem:~/1$ 
argument1
var1 is

How to set var1 from first commandline argument?

Answer (score 34):

The correct assignment is simply the following, with no spaces on either side of the equal sign:

```
var1=$1
```

The command `set var1 = $1` actually does the following:

1. Sets the value of `$1` to "var1"
2. Sets the value of `$2` to "="
3. Sets the value of `$3` to the original first parameter `$1`.

Comment: Thanks, Im newbie in bash

Comment: +1. To summarize: Do not use `set` for variable assignment (it serves a different purpose - see `help set`); instead, use `<varname>=<value>`, and be sure not to use whitespace on either side of the `=`.

Comment: @glennjackman, nowhere does that link explain how to set a variable.

Comment: You're right. Amazing it took 6 years for someone to point that out.

Comment: @Daniel It's fine; a parameter expansion on the RHS of an assignment is not subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion. If you are more comfortable doing so, `var="$1"` is fine as well; the quotes are removed as usual before assigning the result to `var`.

Comment: Thanks for specifying "with no spaces on either side of the equal sign"